# Call a factory method with a string instead an object

Tags: objective-c, ios

Im just wondering whether there is a way (in Objective-C and iPad) to call a factory method where I build the name of the object on the fly with a string.

e.g. I have a class XYZ and several factory methods

```
 +(XYZ *) A;
 +(XYZ *) B;
 +(XYX *) C
```

I would normally call it like

```
 [XYZ A];
 [XYZ B];
 [XYZ C];
```

But I want to be able to call it dynamically with a string e.g.

```
 NSString *s; 
 ...
 s = @"B";
 [XYZ s];
```

I hope you get my point.

Thank you.

Comment: `NSSelectorFromString()`

Comment: i.e. [XYZ NSSelectorFromString(@"B")]
Right?

Comment: @boscarol: No. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use [`NSSelectorFromString()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSelectorFromString) to convert an `NSString*` into a `SEL` (which is the same type that `@selector()` gives you). You can then call this with [`-performSelector:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/performSelector%3a) and its variants.

```
[XYZ performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(s)];
```

`-performSelector:` is useful for methods that take no arguments and return `id` or `void`. [`-performSelector:withObject:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/performSelector%3awithObject%3a) and [`-performSelector:withObject:withObject:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/performSelector%3awithObject%3awithObject%3a) are variants that take 1 or 2 `id`-typed parameters. If you need more parameters than that, or you need a parameter or return value that isn't `id`, then you can use [`NSInvocation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/) instead to set up the method call. Note that `NSInvocation` is (relatively) expensive, so it should only be used when there's no other way.